# Trying to grep out the stderr from ls command

Tags: bash, shell

So I am having an issue with piping an `ls` command to `grep`. Im basically running `ls -l` within a for loop on a file where some are missing, so it gives me the `No file or directory found` error for three of the lines. What I can't figure out is how to parse only those lines and output it to another file/variable.

```
for i in $file
do
    line=`/bin/echo $i | sed 's/source1_dir/dest1_dir/g'`
    /bin/ls -l $line | grep -i "No file"
done
```

When I try to do that, it outputs the three errors but I am unable to pipe those errors to another file, if that makes sense. I think it's an issue with stderr but I'm not sure.

Comment: Use `2 > file` or `2 > $var` to save the stderr.

Comment: Thanks I tried that before and nothing outputs to the file, but the errors are gone in the ls output. I did ls -l $line 2> file and the file outputs nothing when I do cat file

Comment: What I see is that `line='/bin/echo... '` should be `line=$(/bin/echo ...)` if you want `$line` to interpret the result of the command.

Comment: Your line should be within backticks ` not ' else do like fedorqui says

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use stderr redirect. Something like:

```
/bin/ls -l $line 2>&1 | grep -i "No file"
```

Answer (score 5):

With bash, you can simply use `|&` to get both `stdout` and `stderr` in the command after the pipe.

But it might be more useful to use a test:

```
if [[ -e "$line" ]]; then
    ls -l "$line"
else
    echo "File $line doesn't exist"
fi
```